# CSS Menu over JavaApplet

Tags: html, css-float

Hello i have created menu using ULs, LIs and CSS styles. On my page i have JavaApplets with maps. I need to have menu over the java applet. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `#menu` is a `<ul>` and `#applet` is an applet:

```
#menu, #menu * { position: relative; z-index: 100; }
#applet { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
```